# I can't bind a key to specific commands for some reason

Tags: key-bindings, frames, zooming

Why can't i remap my keys with the following command in my spacemacs `init.el` file?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'frm-zoom-in)
```

For some reason,it gives me the following error:

`Wrong type argument,commandp, frm-zoom-in.`

When I try to wrap it into a custom function:

```
(defun frm-zoom-plus (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (frm-zoom-in arg "u"))
```

It gives me the following error: `Symbol's function definition is void: frm-zoom-in`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `frm-zoom-in` does not seem to be a defined function. Indeed, it's not defined in vanilla Emacs (although Spacemacs might be different). Why do you think that it *is* defined? Can you point us to its definition?

Comment: Try `F1 f the-function` to see whether the function you want to use is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the library that defines that function.

---

But I suspect that you have the command name wrong, and you're using library [`zoom-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el). If so, the command is named `zoom-frm-in`, not `frm-zoom-in`.

Of course it's possible that some other library defined a command with a similar command, and that's what you want. If so, just load that library.

Comment: But even if i go M-x, load-library, then select zoom-frm.el, i get the same error output. What should i do?

Comment: i changed my init file to:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'frm-zoom-in)

error message is: wrong type argument,commandp,frm-zoom-in

Comment: Are you trying to use library zoom-frm.el or some other library? If the former, the command is zoom-frm-in, not frm-zoom-in. When you tried to load it, did it load? It sounds like it didn't. Is the file or its directory in your `load-path`? If not, `load-library` and `require` won't find it.